# Screen glitch while playing Minecraft on Ubuntu

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I play Minecraft snapshot 20w09a on Ubuntu 18.04, after about 20 minutes in game, I get a glitch that looks like this:[image: weird screen glitch]

Does anybody know what this is caused by/how to fix it? So far the only thing that seems to help is restarting, but the problem always comes back later.